# XCode uploading data files to iPad "Permission Denied"?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to upload some modified data files to my app using XCode 5. My app takes makes modifications to an sqlite database that I want to be able to restore easily for testing purposes.

So I downloaded the datafiles from the app (containing the db) with the intention of reuploading it later after the app does some modifications to the db.

I download the files through the Organizer -> My iPad -> Applications -> Download (under Data files in Sandbox). I want to reupload by the Upload button right next to it.

However when I try to upload it returns the error "Permission Denied". There is nothing in the device logs indicating what exactly what permissions I need.

Does anyone know of the proper build settings or device settings I need to be allowed to upload modified datafiles for my App?

Comment: Did you quit the app on your ipad before uploading? If the files are open and your app is in the background, you would not be able to replace them.

Comment: @RyanR Yep stopped debugging and made sure the app was not running.

Comment: @RyanR Nope you're right. Turns out the app was running even though I hit Stop in XCode, I double tapped home button to bring up running apps and there it was paused in the state just before startup weirdly. If you write up the comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verify the App isn't running on the device (even in the background), as that can lock files in its data directory.

Answer (score 24):

I've found that the cached Snapshots can interfere with the upload process. If you go into the downloaded app data folder and remove the Snapshot image, then try to re-upload to the device, it should work.

Comment: that's /Library/Caches/Snapshots in the downloaded .xcappdata bundle

Comment: Only remove the image files, not the folders!

Answer (score 0):

With xcode 5.1 I have noticed that it always fails for the first time. Second time it succeeds.